# How to upload ASP.NET project on github

Tags: asp.net, github

I'm a newbie to Git, sorry about the very basic question

I tried to follow online tutuorial, but got struck here:
[image]

There should be a publish button here but I just can't find it

Answer (score 0):

You should configure a remote repository. After that PUSH is your friend.